# My custom Wordpress plugin is causing a white screen in the admin area when navigating to a different admin menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Ok.. I will try and be as detailed as I can with the issue I'm having. Also there is a good chance I am doing something wrong in my php / wordpress code as I've not been using the language for very long.

I have created two wordpress plugins. One is a gallery and one is a page building plugin. Both plugins work fine from the front end and the admin area. The problem occurs when you navigate away from the plugin settings page in the admin area, any other admin area link you navigate to will appear as a blank page, except if you click on the root plugin settings link or the root settings link for the other plugin I have made (works both ways).

Also the issue is not reproduced if you navigate away from either of the plugins root menu. It is only when you are on the Add New / Edit section of the plugin. This area of the plugin is accessing the $wpdb object and is pulling data from the SQL table I have created for each plugin. Also the both Add New / Edit pages are making use of the Media Uploader with the use of wp_equeue_media().

I have tried turning on all manner of logs none of which are reporting / displaying anything. I have tried commenting out the call to $wpdb and wp_equeue_media(). I have tried adjusting the php memory limits and those in wp-config.php. None of this has worked.

Here is the code for the gallery plugin as it is the smaller of the two and they have both been built in a similar way...

This is the main plugin page php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: BoxGallery
 * Plugin URI: asd
 * Description: asd
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: asd
 * Author URI: asd
 * License: GPL2
**/

// GLOBALS
global $boxgal_table_name;
global $boxgal_galleries;
global $toplevel_slug;

// INCLUDES
include('admin/boxgal-admin.php');

function boxgal_init()
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $boxgal_table_name;
    global $boxgal_galleries;

    global $toplevel_slug;
    $toplevel_slug = 'boxgallery';  

    $boxgal_table_name = $wpdb->prefix."boxgal";

    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$boxgal_table_name'") == $boxgal_table_name)
        $boxgal_galleries = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $boxgal_table_name");
}
add_action('init', 'boxgal_init'); 

function boxgal_enqueue()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('box-slider', plugins_url('/slider/box-slider.js', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style('box-slider-style', plugins_url('/slider/box-slider-style.css', __FILE__ ));   
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'boxgal_enqueue');

function boxgal_install() 
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $boxgal_table_name;  
    $boxgal_table_name = $wpdb->prefix."boxgal";

    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$boxgal_table_name'") != $boxgal_table_name) { 
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$boxgal_table_name.'(
                id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                name VARCHAR(255),
                slug VARCHAR(255),
                size_x INTEGER,
                size_y INTEGER,
                images VARCHAR(255),
                trans_type VARCHAR(255),
                trans_time INTEGER,
                slide_hold INTEGER,             
                PRIMARY KEY  (id))';

        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'boxgal_install');

function boxgal_shortcode($atts)
{
    if (isset($atts['tag'])) {      
        global $boxgal_galleries;
        $tag = $atts['tag'];

        $tag_gallery = null;
        $tag_gallery_imgs;      
        foreach ($boxgal_galleries as $gallery) {
            if ($tag == $gallery->slug) {
                $tag_gallery = $gallery;
                $tag_gallery_imgs = explode(",", $tag_gallery->images);
                break;  
            }               
        }

        if ($tag_gallery == null) {
            return '<span style="color:#F00;"><b>BoxGallery </b>- Could not find the '.$tag.' gallery. Please check spelling and that the gallery exists.</span>';  
        }
        else 
        {
            $output_html = '<script type="text/javascript">'.
                                'slideWidth = '.$tag_gallery->size_x.';'.
                                'slideHeight = '.$tag_gallery->size_y.';'.
                                'currentTransition = "'.$tag_gallery->trans_type.'";'.
                                'transitionTime = '.$tag_gallery->trans_time.';'.
                                'slideHold = '.$tag_gallery->slide_hold.';'.
                            '</script>';    
            $output_html .= '<div id="boxslider">';
            for($i = 0; $i < count($tag_gallery_imgs); $i++) 
            {
                $attachment = get_post($tag_gallery_imgs[$i]);
                $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src($tag_gallery_imgs[$i], 'full');              
                $output_html .= '<div class="boxslider_slide" style="background-image: url('.$image_attributes[0].')">'.
                                    '<div class="boxslider_caption">'.
                                        '<p><b>'.$attachment->post_title.'</b></p>'.
                                        '<p>'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'</p>'.
                                    '</div>'.                                   
                                '</div>';               
            }
            $output_html .= '</div>';
            return $output_html;
        }
    }
    else
        return '<span style="color:#F00;"><b>BoxGallery </b>- You forgot the tag attribute! i.e. [boxgal tag="gallery_tag"]</span>';
}
add_shortcode('boxgal', 'boxgal_shortcode');

?>
```

This is the admin include php

```
<?php
function boxgal_menu()
{
    global $toplevel_slug;

    add_menu_page('BoxGallery options', 'BoxGallery', 'manage_options', $toplevel_slug, 'boxgal_options');
    add_submenu_page($toplevel_slug, 'Add new gallery', 'Add new...', 'manage_options', $toplevel_slug.'_add', 'boxgal_options_addnew');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'boxgal_menu');

function boxgal_admin_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('boxgal-admin', plugins_url('/boxgal-admin.js', __FILE__ ));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','boxgal_admin_enqueue');

function boxgal_options()
{   
    global $wpdb;
    global $boxgal_table_name;
    global $boxgal_galleries;
    global $toplevel_slug;

    if (isset($_GET['delid']))
    {
        $wpdb->delete($boxgal_table_name, array('id' => $_GET['delid']));
        $boxgal_galleries = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $boxgal_table_name");     
    }

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>BoxGallery</h2>
        <table class="widefat" style="margin: 10px 0px 50px 0px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Gallery Name</th>
                    <th>Gallery Tag</th>
                    <th>Images</th>        
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <th>Gallery Name</th>                
                <th>Gallery Tag</th>
                <th>Images</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody id="gallery_table">
            <?php               
                foreach ($boxgal_galleries as $gallery) {
                    $table_row = '';
                    $table_row .= '<tr>';
                    $table_row .= '<td><a href="'.admin_url('admin.php').'/?page='.$toplevel_slug.'_add&tag='.$gallery->slug.'">'.$gallery->name.'</a></td>';
                    $table_row .= '<td>'.$gallery->slug.'</td>';
                    $gal_imgs = explode(',', $gallery->images);
                    $table_row .= '<td>';
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($gal_imgs); $i++)
                        $table_row .= wp_get_attachment_image($gal_imgs[$i]);               
                    $table_row .= '</td>';
                    $table_row .= '<td><a href="'.admin_url('admin.php').'/?page='.$toplevel_slug.'&delid='.$gallery->id.'">Delete</a></td>';
                    $table_row .= '</tr>';
                    echo $table_row;
                }
            ?>              
            </tbody>
        </table>   
    </div>
    <?php   
}

function boxgal_options_addnew()
{   
    wp_enqueue_media(); 

    $edit_page = isset($_GET['tag']);

    if ($edit_page)
    {   
        global $wpdb;
        global $boxgal_table_name;
        global $boxgal_galleries;
        global $toplevel_slug;

        $tag = $_GET['tag'];

        $tag_gallery = null;
        $tag_gallery_imgs;      
        foreach ($boxgal_galleries as $gallery) 
        {
            if ($tag == $gallery->slug) 
            {
                $tag_gallery = $gallery;
                $tag_gallery_imgs = explode(",", $tag_gallery->images);             
                break;  
            }               
        }
    }           
    ?>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        currentImgIds = Array(<?php echo $tag_gallery->images; ?>);
    </script>   
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php if (!$edit_page) { ?>
            <h2>Add new</h2>    
        <?php } else { ?>
            <h2>Edit "<?php echo $tag_gallery->name; ?>"</h2>
        <?php } ?>          
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="boxgal_name">Gallery Name:</label></th>
                <td><input name="boxgal_name" type="text" id="boxgal_name" value="<?php if($edit_page) echo $tag_gallery->name; ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="boxgal_slug">Gallery Tag:</label></th>
                <td><input name="boxgal_slug" type="text" id="boxgal_slug" value="<?php if($edit_page) echo $tag_gallery->slug; ?>" class="regular-text" />
                <p class="description">This is the tag that will be used in the BoxGallery shortcode. This should contain no white-space / spaces.</p></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="boxgal_size_x">Size:</label></th>
                <td><input name="boxgal_size_x" type="text" id="boxgal_size_x" value="<?php if($edit_page) echo $tag_gallery->size_x; ?>" class="regular-text" style="width: 50px;" /> x 
                <input name="boxgal_size_y" type="text" id="boxgal_size_y" value="<?php if($edit_page) echo $tag_gallery->size_y; ?>" class="regular-text" style="width: 50px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="boxgal_transtype">Transition Type:</label></th>
                <td>
                    <?php 
                    if($edit_page)
                        $trans_type = $tag_gallery->trans_type;
                    ?>
                    <select id="boxgal_transtype">
                      <option <?php if ($edit_page && $trans_type == 'fade') echo 'selected'; ?> value="boxgal_tt_fade">Fade</option>
                      <option <?php if ($edit_page && $trans_type == 'slide-left') echo 'selected'; ?> value="boxgal_tt_slide-left">Slide Left</option>
                      <option <?php if ($edit_page && $trans_type == 'slide-right') echo 'selected'; ?> value="boxgal_tt_slide-right">Slide Right</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="boxgal_tt_time">Transition Time:</label></th>
                <td><input name="boxgal_tt_time" type="text" id="boxgal_tt_time" value="<?php if($edit_page) echo $tag_gallery->trans_time; ?>" class="regular-text" style="width: 50px;" />
                <p class="description">How long in milliseconds should the transition take?</p></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="boxgal_hold_time">Slide Hold:</label></th>
                <td><input name="boxgal_hold_time" type="text" id="boxgal_hold_time" value="<?php if($edit_page) echo $tag_gallery->slide_hold; ?>" class="regular-text" style="width: 50px;" />
                <p class="description">How long in milliseconds should the slide be on screen for?</p></td>
            </tr>           
        </table>
        <div style="margin: 50px 0px 10px 0px;">
            <input type="submit" class="button-secondary" id="add_image" value="Add Image" />
        </div>
        <table class="widefat" style="margin: 10px 0px 50px 0px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Caption</th>       
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Caption</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody id="gallery_table">
                <?php if ($edit_page) 
                {                   
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($tag_gallery_imgs); $i++)
                    {   
                        $attachment = get_post($tag_gallery_imgs[$i]);  
                        echo '<tr>';                                    
                        echo '<td>'.wp_get_attachment_image($tag_gallery_imgs[$i]).'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'</td>';
                        echo '<td><a id="'.$tag_gallery_imgs[$i].'" class="boxgal_del" href="#">Delete</a></td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                }
                ?>                         
            </tbody>
        </table>   
        <input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="save_gallery" value="Save Gallery" id="save_gallery" />             
    </div>
    <?php
}


function boxgal_save_callback() 
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $boxgal_table_name;
    global $boxgal_galleries;

    $boxgal_name = $_POST['boxgal_name'];
    $boxgal_slug = $_POST['boxgal_slug'];
    $boxgal_size_x = $_POST['boxgal_size_x'];   
    $boxgal_size_y = $_POST['boxgal_size_y'];
    $boxgal_transtype = $_POST['boxgal_transtype'];
    $boxgal_tt_time = $_POST['boxgal_tt_time'];
    $boxgal_hold_time = $_POST['boxgal_hold_time'];

    $boxgal_img_ids = "";   
    $img_count = count($_POST['boxgal_img_ids']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $img_count; $i++) 
    {
        $boxgal_img_ids .= $_POST['boxgal_img_ids'][$i];
        if ($i < $img_count - 1)
            $boxgal_img_ids .= ",";
    }       

    $table_id = -1;
    foreach ($boxgal_galleries as $gallery) 
    {
        if ($boxgal_slug == $gallery->slug) 
        {
            $table_id = $gallery->id;
            break;  
        }               
    }

    if ($table_id != -1)
    {   
        $wpdb->update($boxgal_table_name, array('name' => $boxgal_name, 
                                                'slug' => $boxgal_slug, 
                                                'size_x' => $boxgal_size_x, 
                                                'size_y' => $boxgal_size_y,
                                                'trans_type' => $boxgal_transtype,
                                                'trans_time' => $boxgal_tt_time,
                                                'slide_hold' => $boxgal_hold_time, 
                                                'images' => $boxgal_img_ids), array('id' => $table_id));
    }
    else
    {
        $wpdb->insert($boxgal_table_name, array('name' => $boxgal_name, 
                                                'slug' => $boxgal_slug, 
                                                'size_x' => $boxgal_size_x, 
                                                'size_y' => $boxgal_size_y, 
                                                'images' => $boxgal_img_ids,
                                                'trans_type' => $boxgal_transtype,
                                                'trans_time' => $boxgal_tt_time,
                                                'slide_hold' => $boxgal_hold_time));
    }   

    echo "Saved";   
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_boxgal_save', 'boxgal_save_callback');
?>
```

Thanks for any help anyone may be able to provide!

Dan

Comment: Go to your wordpress `wp-config.php` file, locate `WP_DEBUG`, change it from `false` to `true`. Come back with the error.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the post, I have tried turning on all the different error reporting and log options in Wordpress and on the server none of which are reporting / displaying anything. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just encountered this problem and found the following suspected factors:
I have several plugins installed, running in local without problem, while I put in production server, white screen of death.

Localhost settings:
PHP 5.3.1

Server:
PHP 5.2.17

So the first suspect is PHP version difference.

The 2nd suspect I found by tracing through the script in Chrome.
First, I found that the white screen of death is actually a HTTP 500 Internal Server error according to the header information. And then after I comment out the following,

```
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);
```

The plugin works again. And the weird part is, this problem occur only several plugin turn on at the same time. Only a single plugin with the above statement does not generate any error.

The combination of the plugin is:

- Paid Membership Pro 1.7.9.1
- Activity Log 1.1
- Theme My Login 6.3.9

They all seems competing for something in the session or header which I have not yet found out exactly the cause. I think this direction might help.

About the error log, because it cause a 500 internal error, it does not output to debug.log, I have added a few "echo" in several lines in the plugin to see which point it generate 500 error.

If that is too difficult to intercept, you may hijack `wp-settings.php`,
in the line with "`... as $plugin)`"
just add a echo `$plugin . "<br>";` line in the foreach loop and all plugin path will be out and it will help to debug.

That's my findings so far.

Note: For official debug method, please refer to [Debugging_in_WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

**Edit 1:**

I have tried PHP version testing in localhost, running an older PHP version than server, it does not generate error.

And
I found that there is a problem in the production server generating 406 error. It seems their(server) settings have problem.
And then I test it a while(5 hours) later, it seems resolved. So, according to the experience from other users during solution findings, Server Settings, PHP caching in the temporary directory are also possible causes to problem. I installed another new set of Wordpress to make sure the original system files are not modified. 5 hours ago, it generate error with strange 406 error too. And then the problem gone, no more white screen in previous plugins when they are all activated.

To test HTTP 406 error in my case by running: http://www.example.com/wp-content/
It should be a blank page, if you see anything other than blank page such as "error in Handling...". It is most likely running into Server problem.

To summary the possible check points:

- Server settings, if there is any HTTP 406 error when running http://www.example.com/wp-content/
- PHP caching (sessions temporary files) or cookies, clean them up
- PHP version (development vs production environment)
- Apache settings in .htaccess, make sure there is no any custom redirect to affect
- If one or two specific plugins conflicts. Check to see if there is anything conflict during `init hook` phase. And check that if their namespaces conflicted.

Comment: Sounds like you had a proper headache with this one! I moved the website to a different server and it all started working again, so I agree that it was a server / software issue.